# Vectorization for loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize this for loop. Any idea?

```
D = 1x8851;

for k = 1:length(D)-1

    P(k) = ((D(k)<=0)&&(D(k+1)>=0))||((D(k)>=0)&&(D(k+1))<0);

 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two things having different signs, it means that their product is negative:

```
P(k) = ((D(k)<=0)&&(D(k+1)>=0))||((D(k)>=0)&&(D(k+1))<0);
```

is the same as:

```
P(k) = ( D(k) * D(k+1) ) <= 0;
```

This is simple to vectorize by simply converting operations to element-wise operations:

```
P = ( D(1:end-1) .* D(2:end) ) <= 0;
```

---

The original construct can be vectorized in the same way, with `&` and `|` being the element-wise counterparts to `&&` and `||`:

```
P = ((D(1:end-1)<=0)&(D(2:end)>=0))|((D(1:end-1)>=0)&(D(2:end))<0);
```

However, the shorter expression requires fewer intermediate matrices and fewer operations, and therefore will be faster.